# Python while loop is keeps repeating

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I am having some problems with the while loop. I am running it on eclipse, and I typed in the source:

```
a = raw_input("Mom im hungry!!!!!! FEED MEEEEE" )
while a != "Feed yourself":
    print("Thats gross")
```

The result is when I type the wrong answer it responds by going:

```
Thats gross 
thats gross
```

and so on.

Comment: Well of course it'll repeat since its condition is always true. Why, did you expect it to do something else?

Comment: To expand upon @DavidZaslavsky comment, you need to copy the assignment of `a` inside the while loop else the condition will never change.

Comment: No i wish you could see... it won't let me input again. it just constantly go's Thats gross thats gross and so on.

Comment: copy the assignment "a" what do you mean

Answer (score 5):

What you really want is:

```
a = raw_input("Mom im hungry!!!!!! FEED MEEEEE" )
while a != "Feed yourself":
  print("Thats gross")
  a = raw_input("Mom im hungry!!!!!! FEED MEEEEE" )    # do something that may alter a !
```

because without the 2nd line in the while loop...

- nothing alters the variable a,
- hence a is still not "Feed yourself"
- hence the condition is true,
- hence the content of the loop repeats itself!

Comment: I am always amazed how these `"no-brainers"` tend to get the most `+ reps`.  If I was a rep wh.re ...  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `raw_input` only executes once, and then `a` keeps its value. If you didn't enter `"Feed yourself"` the first time, it will loop forever.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = raw_input("Mom im hungry!!!!!! FEED MEEEEE" )
while a != "Feed yourself":
    print("Thats gross")
    a = raw_input("Mom im hungry!!!!!! FEED MEEEEE" )
```